# iOS url scheme to open specific youtube and soundcloud page in respective apps?

Tags: ios, url, youtube, soundcloud

Is there anyway to use an iOS URL Scheme to open the YouTube and Soundcloud iOS Applications to a particular user's profile?

I've tried youtube://user/myusername and soundcloud:user:myusername but they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know for youtube, but for SoundCloud, `soundcloud:users:id` should work fine.

Comment: That worked for soundcloud! I'll mark it as the answer and perhaps ask a separate one for youtube. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@vince is right and you can use SoundCloud's [/resolve](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve) endpoint to retrieve an user's id